# Nginx and Rails gzip configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, gzip

I have problem with nginx + gzip + rails configuration. My nging.conf looks like this:

```
gzip on;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_min_length  1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;      
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";        
gzip_vary on;
```

The problem is that rails generated css files are not gziped. For example this url

```
http://host.com/stylesheets/main.css?1324378206
```

is not gziped (checked in firefox), but when I remove rails generated timestamp it shows gzipped:

```
http://host.com/stylesheets/main.css
```

Can anyone know how to make first url to be gzipped also?

Answer (score 2):

It seems some caching in our company local network was the reason why some files seemed not to be gzipped. When I connect from home everything was ok.